# error can not open file in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am getting the error of :

```
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ylmtr.obj' in visual studio 2013
```

In the properties of my project I made the following configurations:

Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies- ylmtr

V/C++ Directories - added to the directories of  include, library, source their configurations from the program parser generator (used to create lexer to make a compiler)

Comment: got the answer !! you should write ylmtr.lib not ylmtr only

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts7eyw4s.aspx

To fix by checking the following possible causes:
Not enough disk space.
File does not exist.
When specifying libraries in a project's property pages dialog box, library names should be separated by spaces (and not commas).
Incorrect filename or path.
Invalid drive specification.
Insufficient file permissions.
Path for filename expands to more than 260 characters.
If the given file is named LNKn, which is a filename generated by the linker for a temporary file, the directory specified in the TMP environment variable may not exist, or more than one directory is specified for the TMP environment variable. (Only one directory path should be specified for the TMP environment variable.)
If the error message occurs for a library name, and you recently ported the .mak file from a previous Microsoft Visual C++ development system, the library may no longer be valid. Ensure that the library still exists in this circumstance.
Another program may have the file open and the linker cannot write to it.
Incorrect LIB environment variable. For information on how to update the LIB environment variable, see VC++ Directories, Projects, Options Dialog Box . Make sure any directories with libraries you need are listed here.